# How to get current date module name with Linq in C#?

Tags: c#, linq, console-application

I am trying to get current date module name from fileName array with linq but failed. How can I compare date from `fileName` with current date in C#

// here date format : MMddyyyy : 08072016

```
string[] fileName = { "Module1_08072016.csv","Module2_08062016.csv","Module3_08042016.csv"};

var name = from item in fileName select item.ToString().Split('_', '.');
                      // where selected item = curent date
```

required Output : Module1   // which have current date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems your date format of file name is `MMddyyyy` if so then you can get single file name this way

```
string[] fileName = { "Module1_08072016.csv", "Module2_08062016.csv", "Module3_08042016.csv" };

var name = (from item in fileName select item.ToString().Split('_', '.')).FirstOrDefault(a => a[1] == DateTime.Now.ToString("MMddyyyy"));

Console.WriteLine(name[0]);
```

and if you want collection of name which have current date then you can get this way

```
var name = (from item in fileName select item.ToString().Split('_', '.'))
        .Where(a => a[1] == DateTime.Now.ToString("MMddyyyy"));

foreach (var n in name)
 {
    Console.WriteLine(n[0]);
 }
```

if you use other date time format in file name then just replace it with the same format here

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("datetime format of filename");
```

Comment: `.Select(a => a)` is useless and can be removed. Then `.Where(/* expression */).FirstOrDefault()` can be replaced with `.FirstOrDefault(/* expression */)`.

Comment: @yashfale what is lack in my answer that you can not accept ? if there is no lack better to consider first who help you, great its helped you, happy coding

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this,

```
            string[] fileName = { "Module1_08072016.csv", "Module2_08062016.csv", "Module3_08042016.csv" };
            string toCheck = DateTime.Now.ToString("MMddyyyy");            
            if (fileName.Any(str => str.Contains(toCheck)))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("yes");
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string [] fileName = { "Module1_08072016.csv","Module2_08062016.csv","Module3_08042016.csv"};   

var currentDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("MMddyyyy");
var fileNames = fileName.Select(e => e.Split('_', '.'))
                .Where(e => e[1] == currentDate)
                .Select(e => e[0]);

foreach(var name in fileNames)
{
    name.Dump(); // Console.WriteLine(name);
}
```